# Limit inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Assume that there exists and continuous function $f: ]1, 2[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the conditions:

$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} f(x) = -\infty \text{ and }  \lim_{x \to 2^-} f(x) = -\infty$$

Show that there exists a $c \in ]1, 2[$, for which all $x \in ]1, 2[$ holds that $f(x) \leq f(c)$

What's the correct approach here?

Comment: A continuous function over a compact set has a maximum (and a minimum). $]1,2[$ is not compact, but since the function goes to $-\infty$ at boundaries, by definition of going to $-\infty$ for a continuous function, you can find $a,b$, $1<a<b<2$ such that $f(x)<f(a)$ for all $1<x<a$ and $f(x)<f(b)$ for all $b<x<2$ and ...

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$

As $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1+} f(x)=-\infty$, there exists $\alpha \in \left] 0, \frac14 \right[$ such that for all $x\in \left] 1, 1+\alpha \right[$, $f(x)<A$

As $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2-} f(x)=-\infty$, there exists $\beta \in \left] 0, \frac14 \right[$ such that for all $x\in \left] 2-\beta, 2 \right[$, $f(x)<A$

We have $1+\alpha < 2-\beta$ (because $\alpha<1/4$ and $\beta<1/4$)

We can consider $[1+\alpha, 2-\beta]$ which is included in $]1,2[$ and as $f$ is continuous on $]1,2[$, it is continuous on $[1+\alpha, 2-\beta]$.

Hence there exits $c\in [1+\alpha, 2-\beta]$ such that for all $x\in [1+\alpha, 2-\beta]$, $f(x) \leq f(c)$.

Moreover $A=f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\leq f(c)$

This implies that

for all $x\in]1,2[, f(x)\leq f(c)$

Comment: Hi! Could you explain where did the $\frac{3}{2}$ for $A$ came from and why did we choose it?

Comment: It's an arbitrary choice. But it is a trick that makes the values taken by f on the two intervals of right and left, below this value, so that they do not exceed the maximum.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's anywhere I could find more examples on this? I tried looking around for "Extreme Value Theorem on an open interval" and info about the "Intermediate Value Property", but it seems that there isn't a lot of examples on these.

Comment: It is an exercise in applying the theorem to the **closed** interval $[1+\alpha,2-\beta]$. But the reason it works on an open interval $]1,2[$ is the condition on the limits equals to $-\infty$ at 1 and 2 and that this is a **maximum**. We cannot really generalize to open intervals, without conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g(x) = \exp(f(x))$. Then $g$ is continuous on $]1, 2[$ and the limits are both zero. (The definition of $f(x) \rightarrow -\infty$ as $x \rightarrow 2^-$ is that for all $M > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) < -M$ whenever $2-\delta < x < 2$. If $\epsilon > 0$ then take $M = -\log(\epsilon)$, so $f(x) < -M = \log(\epsilon)$ implies $g(x) < \epsilon$.)

Extend $g$ to $\tilde{g}: [1, 2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by continuity, with $\tilde{g}(1) = \tilde{g}(2) = 0$. Note $\tilde{g} > 0$ in $]1, 2[$ since $\exp > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $[1, 2]$ is compact, $\tilde{g}$ attains a maximum in $[1, 2]$, in fact a positive maximum $]1, 2[$ since $\tilde{g}(1) = \tilde{g}(2) = 0$, and therefore $g$ and $f$ also have a maximum (in $]1, 2[$).

Note this is essentially the same style of argument as the previous answer; by continuity the maximum will occur away from the endpoints.